# C# Check if XML contains string

Tags: c#, xml, boolean, contains

I need to list my series so I coded a little tool that saves the series names in a certain folder into a xml file.
I used to have a txt-File but that got messy over time.

This tool updates the series list in the txt file at a certain point of time.
Currently I use this code:

```
List<string> seriesList = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\path\series.txt").ToList();
bool contains = seriesList.Contains(series, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (contains)
{
    return;
} 
else 
{
    addToList()
}
```

The series names in my txt get saved like this:

> Krypton.
>
> NCIS.Los.Angeles.

etc.

In my xml file the series names get listed as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<collection>
  <series>Krypton.</series>
  <series>NCIS.Los.Angeles.</series>
</collection>
```

Now I need something like my "contains"-function like above.
It would be nice if this would work without a for-loop.

---

EDIT: (done)

```
XDocument xDocSload = XDocument.Load(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\settings\series.xml");

var sList = xDocSload.Root.Elements("seriesName").Select(element => element.Value).ToList();

List<string> seriesList = sList;

bool contains = seriesList.Contains(series, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (contains)
{
...
```

Comment: So, deseralize the XML and check if `collection.Series.Contains("foo")`? What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm missing something in this question

Answer (score 0):

The lines are the strings.  You want to see if any of the strings contains a substring - so just use LINQ's Any.

(Also get rid of the return, makes code harder to read)

`var isThere = seriesList.Any(s => s.Contains(series, ));
if(!isThere)
{
    addToList();
}`

Comment: Your code is based on the "seriesList" which contains the strings from the txt. I don't want to use the txt anymore. I need to check if the xml contains a certain string (Series Name)

Comment: XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\settings\series.xml");